# TRAPEZIUMS arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The word TRAPEZIUMS is arranged in a line.

(i) Find the number of different arrangements if there are no restrictions.

10!

(ii) Find the number of different arrangements if all the vowels are separated.

$\binom 74 \times 4!  \times 6!$

(iii) Find the probability that the arrangement starts and ends with a consonant and that all the vowels are together.

$\frac{5\times 4! \times 6!}{10!}$

(iv) Now 5 letters are to be chosen from TRAPEZIUMS. Find the number of different selections with at least two consonants.

$\binom {10}{5} - \binom {6}{1}$

I have provided the answers to the 4 parts of the question. Are they all correct? If not what is done incorrectly? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I verified each of your answers as correct.

Comment: _Sometimes_ it happens one makes two or more mistakes that cancel each other, thus leading to a correct result despite an erroneous solution. So you might want to provide some details about your analysis of the problem and the way you came to the results, so the full solution could get validated. (That would also make your question and answers more useful for other users of this site.)

Comment: "Trapeziums" is not a word. The plural of "trapezium" is "trapezia".